# Post method not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using HMVC codeigniter. I am trying to use jquery ajax first time. When i use POST then it gives undefined error while it response me the data while using GET.

```
         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: filelink+"cart/add_cart_item",
          data: {"product_id":id,"quantity":qty,"ajax":"1"},
          dataType: "json",
              success: function(msg){
           alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
           },
               error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
           alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
      });
```

**What I have tried so far after googling and SO-ing-**

1. my file url location is accessible directly. I checked it. giving response.
2. Firebug is giving 500 internal server error for the same file.
3. Using Get is responding me back well
4. added json in the datatype

**controller function**

```
  class Cart extends CI_Controller { // Our Cart class extends the Controller class

  function __construct()
     {
    parent::__construct();  
    $this->template->set('controller', $this);
     }

  function _remap()
    {
       $uri2 = $this->uri->segment(2);  
       if (is_numeric($uri2) OR $uri2 == FALSE) {
        $this->index(); 
       } else if ($uri2 == 'add_cart_item') {
        $this->add_cart_item();
       } else if ($uri2 == 'show_cart') {
        $this->show_cart();
       }
     }

function add_cart_item(){
      echo "asdfsadfdsf";
      exit; 
    }
  }
```

can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($this->input->post('product_id'));` ? Does it output anything?

Comment: @vikassharma: what does filelink contains?

Comment: @vikassharma and what does your base_url() look like? Have you tried using the fully qualified url?or just the name of the controller plus the method?

Comment: @vikassharma is your controller working if you access it normally? I see that you're actually using hmvc but your'e still extending ci_Controller instead of Mx_controller.

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu I am pretty new to this codeigniter and hmvc. Actually this is the way other controller are designed. other pages are using a main.php as outer template file and there content are showing in between them by load partial. may be this is causing problem ???? they all are using ci_controller.I copied the same ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the solution. The problem was due to CI_TOKEN which is sent with the FORM. That was absent and due to which POST method was giving 500 Internal server Error. I added following in my view file.

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

and sent ci_token with the ajax post request.

```
 var ci_token = formObj.find('input[name=ci_token]').val();
 var qty = 1;
 var dataString = 'product_id='+ id + '&quantity=' + qty + '&ajax=' + 1 
 +'&ci_token=' +            ci_token;
```

This solved the problem. I am not sure but this is called CSRF related some problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are possible reasons for your problem

You might be using model which is not loaded.
There might be some code problem in the model.
You may not be returning anything from your model and echo it.
Also if you need the data back use echo json_encode($data)

Comment: Hi Raheel, I edited my code. Please have a look at the controller. I dont used any model. Can this be the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this problem arises when you have loaded the site as https://example.com but the url in your ajax call is http://example.com .

Comment: But I am using the same <? base_url() ?> through out the website. Url is just fine..

Answer (score 0):

you have used _remap function and after getting $uri2  there is an if check which is checking the quantity variable you have passed in your ajax request and it may have integer value as obvious may contain some integer.
there for

```
$this->uri->segment();
```

returns you:

```
product_id=id
quantity=qty
ajax=1
```

and you take value 2 that is quantity by calling

```
$uri2 = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

it will return quantity to you and you have not defined an index() function in your code which gives 500 error

```
function _remap()
{
   $uri2 = $this->uri->segment(2);  
   if (is_numeric($uri2) OR $uri2 == FALSE) {
    $this->index(); 
   } else if ($uri2 == 'add_cart_item') {
    $this->add_cart_item();
   } else if ($uri2 == 'show_cart') {
    $this->show_cart();
   }
 }
```